# I can't understand the calculations in drag and drop example

Tags: javascript

I can't understand the **calculations** in this code .
It's a video on youtube and this is the link for it : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jfYWwQrtzzY
I can't understand how he calculated the target element and how to put the dragged element in certain position.

```
const draggables = document.querySelectorAll(".draggable");
const containers = document.querySelectorAll(".container");

draggables.forEach((draggable) => {
  draggable.addEventListener("dragstart", () => {
    draggable.classList.add("dragging");
  });
  draggable.addEventListener("dragend", () => {
    draggable.classList.remove("dragging");
  });
});

containers.forEach((container) => {
  container.addEventListener("dragover", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const afterElement = getDragAfterElement(container, e.clientY);
    const draggable = document.querySelector(".dragging");
    if (afterElement == null) {
      container.appendChild(draggable);
    }else{
      container.insertBefore(draggable,afterElement);
    }
  });
});

function getDragAfterElement(container, y) {
  const draggableElements = [
    ...container.querySelectorAll(".draggable:not(.dragging)"),
  ];
  return draggableElements.reduce(
    (closest, child) => {
      const box = child.getBoundingClientRect();
      const offset = y - box.top - box.height / 2;
      if (offset < 0 && offset > closest.offset) {
        return { offset: offset, element: child };
      } else {
        return closest;
      }
    },
    { offset: Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY }
  ).element;
}
```

Comment: what calculation? The offset line?

Comment: @epascarello  the reduce function as a whole exactly and why using NEGATIVE_INFINITY

Comment: Do you know how reduce works? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce You need to start with an initial value, so the person started with the smallest number possible. The mouse position is based off the top left of the page so the calculation is to determine where the cursor is located inside of the middle of the element. console.log() is your friend here so you can see what the values are.

Comment: @epascarello Thanks alot